# Simplifying Inverse Matrices Expression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, products, associativity

On pg. 95 of Howard Anton's Elementary Linear Algebra, it asks to simplify

$$(AB)^{-1}(AC)^{-1}(D^{-1}C^{-1})^{-1}D^{-1}$$

The answer is supposed to be $B^{-1}$ but I end up with $B^{-1}A^{-1}A^{-1}$

First, I undid all the brackets which led to $B^{-1}A^{-1}C^{-1}A^{-1}CDD^{-1}$

I "cancelled out" $CC^{-1}$ and $DD^{-1}$ using the associative property of matrix multiplication but not sure how to simplify it any further.

I guess $A^{-1}A^{-1} =(AA)^{-1} = (A^2)^{-1}$ (not 100% here).

However, I still have $B^{-1}(A^2)^{-1}.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks.  Yesterday, it mathjaxed it automatically.

Comment: "*Yesterday it mathjaxed it automatically*", no it wasn't automatic.  It was another user who saw that it needed to be done and took it upon him/herself to manually do it for you.

Comment: @JMoravitz, got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer isn't $B^{-1}$. It isn't $B^{-1}A^{-2}$ either.

You can't cancel out $CC^{-1}$ since there isn't a $CC^{-1}$ there
($CA^{-1}C^{-1}$ may not equal $CC^{-1}A^{-1}$).

Comment: I guess it might be a typo and associativity does not apply for inverses?

Comment: @NickAnoyot The associative property allows you to say $(C^{-1}A^{-1})C=C^{-1}(A^{-1}C)$.  Basically, it allows you to move the parentheses.  It does not allow you to exchange the order of 2 matrices being multiplied.  Matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: @Mike, well noted.  $(C^{-1}A^{-1})C = C^{-1}CA^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is years old, but I just checked that book and found that the expression is actually $(AB)^{-1}(AC^{-1})(D^{-1}C^{-1})^{-1}D^{-1}$, in which case it would simplify to $B^{-1}A^{-1}AC^{-1}CDD^{-1}=B^{-1}$.